# BottomSheetDialogFragment exposed height

Tags: android, dialog, bottom-sheet

It seems BottomSheetDialogFragment is coded with an anchor, where if your fragment layout exceeds `360dp` in height `onShow()` will cause the dialog to peek to `360dp` and you have to manually drag the sheet up to show all of your layout.

**any way to bypass this behavior or any other recommendations for a modal bottom dialog where I can use a fragment?**

you may check the behavior as follows

*Activity.java*

```
            MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog();
            mtDialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(),"my_dialog_fragment");
```

*MyDialog.java*

```
public class MyDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment{
   public View onCreate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, container, false);
   }
}
```

*dialog.xml*

```
<FrameLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="432dp"
    android:backgroud="@color/blue"/>
```

that's pretty much the code. I've tried using `setStyle` and creating a BottomSheetDialog style and all those permutations and nope. but setting the height to 360dp is where it expands fully, but I need some more area.

Answer (score 4):

OP here answering the Q.

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    @Override
    public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
        dialog.setContentView(v);

        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) v.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
        CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();
        ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
}
```

The above fixed the issue of not expanding to the full height declared in the layout. Might want to add a check on the behavior to make sure its not null. Now just need to add my arithmetic, not sure if it needs to be on oncreateview or here in setup dialog... we shall see.

Happy coding :)